# PHP if, else statement. Form and date of birth validation

Tags: php, html, validation, if-statement

Im writing code practicing PHP **if and else statements** and **form validation**.

the basic idea is this:
After entering name, **DOB** , and email and clicking the submit button, **Based on the DOB  they enter** the button leads them to leads to:

-a page telling them they are too young to drink **(notwelcome.php)**

**OR**

-a page telling them they can order a drink **(welcome.php)**

The 2 pages **(notwelcome.php & welcome.php)** are pulled from separate file called **action.php** saved like this:

```
<?php
include('welcome.php');
include('notwelcome.php');
?>
```

This is what i have been trying ..but its not working. nothing happens.. Its as if the if else code isnt even there :(

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {

    $dob = $_POST['dob'];

    if (isset ($_POST['dob'] )> 12/31/1992) {
        header("Location: notwelcome.php");
} else {
        header("Location: welcome.php");}
}
?>
```

Help. Im a beginner and i have hit a small bump in the road in my code.

additional infor:

HTML Code is like this:

```
    <div style="text-align: center;">

        <h2>FORM & PHP</h2>

        <h3>WHINE & DINE</h3>
        <form action="action.php" method="post">
           Full Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
           Date of Birth: <input type="date" name="dob"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">

        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: `12/31/1992` is 12 divided by 31 divided by 1992... suggest you read a bit about dates in PHP

Comment: do you want to include either (xor) PHP documents based upon the condition? If so, trying subbing the include in the if bodies, better, though, to just execute functionality from those files rather than include them based upon evaluation of an if.

Comment: And `isset ($_POST['dob'] )> 12/31/1992` won't (strictly speaking) work either. `isset()` returns a boolean so your comparison doesn't make sense. Also I'm currently wondering where you defined your `if/else` block…in `action.php`?

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/#date_and_time

Comment: What if 10 people were all born on the very same day/month/year? (And I'm being conservative about this number) If this is just an exercise then that's ok, however if you're going to be using this in a real world situation, then I suggest you check for duplicate email addresses instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Also, you don't need to `include` those files unless you want them showing up on the page before you process the form. I would check to make sure you have the relative path correct. You would also want to make it so users enter the DOB in the right format.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['dob'])) {

    $dob = $_POST['dob'];

    if ($dob > date("m/d/Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') - 21))) {
        header("Location: notwelcome.php");
    } else {
        header("Location: welcome.php");}
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I appreciate you for your response.
im still not able to make it work, i think the issue is probably on my end here not that you code wasn't correct.

and to answer your question, I had created the action.php and "Included"  the files as i did not know how else to do it, since the  form tag can only have one "Action". if you know a better way, i would appreciate any suggestions. and

another question is if i decided to keep the action.php file, is the "if-else" statement defined in there as well?

also, yes the user is entering the correct date format

Comment: try putting this if statement at the the top of your html, that way it is all one file. Then make sure that it is a php file, and delete the action="action.php" from your form. Then put a different echo inside each of the possibilities just to see if the if statement to check the date is working (for example echo 'welcome';).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. In php code you can add additional if conditions to check validity of ranges.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['month']) && isset($_POST['year']) ) 
{
    $dob = date_format (date_create ($_POST['year']."-".$_POST['month']."-".$_POST['date']), "Y-m-d");
    if ($dob > date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') - 21)))
      {
        header("Location: notwelcome.php");
      } 
    else 
      {
        header("Location: welcome.php"); 
      }
}
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">

        <h2>FORM & PHP</h2>

        <h3>WHINE & DINE</h3>
        <form action="r.php" method="post">
           Full Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
           Date of Birth: <select name="month">
<option value="01">January</option><option value="02">February</option><option value="03">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option><option value="05">May</option><option value="06">June</option>
<option value="07">July</option><option value="08">August</option><option value="09">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option><option value="11">November</option><option value="12">December</option></select> <select name="date" >
<option value="1">01</option><option value="2">02</option><option value="3">03</option>
<option value="4">04</option><option value="5">05</option><option value="6">06</option>
<option value="7">07</option><option value="8">08</option><option value="9">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option>
</select> <input name="year" type="text" id="year" size="4" maxlength="4"> <span>(YYYY)</span>
<br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>          
</body>     
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant way to do it, but this worked for me:

```
if(isset($_POST['dob'])) { $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    list($date,$time) = explode(" ", $dob);
    list($year,$month,$day) = explode("-",$date);
    $years  = date("Y") - $year;
    $months = date("m") - $month;
    $days   = date("d") - $day;
        if (($years > 21) || ($years == 21 && $months > 0) || ($years == 21 && $months == 0 && $days >= 0)) {
        header("Location: welcome.php");
        } else {
        header("Location: notwelcome.php");
        }
}
```

Subtracting the birth year from the current year, the birth month from the current month and the birth day from the current day, this basically runs up to three tests. First, if the current year is more than 21 years after the person's birth year, they're legal. Second, if it's 21 years after the person's birth year but it's after their birth month, they're legal. Finally, if it's 21 years after the person's birth year and it happens to be their birth month and the day of the month is greater than or equal to the person's birth day, they're legal. If none of those things are true, they're under 21.

Comment: PHP >= 5.3 has DateTime::diff which is probably a cleaner way.