# how can i set validation rules for a date of birth input

Tags: php, html

How can I set date of birth validations for a registration form?

I tried comparing the dob entered with the current date but it didn't work.

```
if (date("d/m/y") > $dob){
    echo "impossible";
}
```

or better how can i make it so that the user doesn't have the option to pick a date that hasn't come yet.

Also how can i compare the dates to not allow someone under 12 to join my website?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883638/php-if-else-statement-form-and-date-of-birth-validation

Comment: `date` formats a date into a string. You meant to use `time`, which gets the date and time as a timestamp. (Oh hail PHP's naming).

Comment: 6 answers, none up voted. At least have to curtsy to do so if it was informational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this seeing as i don't want to use jquery for this

```
if (isset($_POST['button'])){
   $dob = $_POST['dob'];

   echo $dob."<br>".date("o-m-d");

   if (date("o-m-d") < $dob){
       echo "<br>invalid dob";
   } else echo "<br>valid dob";
}
```

When I pick 31/01/2016 the script gives

```
2016-01-31
2016-01-09
invalid dob
```

Answer (score 1):

Now in HTML5 you can set date type input limited to its minimum an maximum value. As below:

```
<input type="date" min="2013-10-01" max="2013-10-20">
```

Now, if you wish to make the maximum date to be the current date, then you can get the current date form PHP `date` function or javascript `Date` function.

But if you want to add client side verification you have to add some similar logic as you have written in PHP. To make it working, you can use `Carbon` library to compare two dates easily.

Comment: This does not defend against attacks changing post and get data that the browser verifies. It should always be checked on server level.

Comment: Yes, it is a client side verification as the question was about picking the date. If anyone want to check in server side, he can do this suing PHP. There is a library called `Carbon` to compare two date.

Answer (score 0):

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Please check this Link.

It is a Jquery module and there you can restrict the min-date and even the max date.

A lot many options are there. Please read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your form input, your `$dob` variable may be used by en_US users which fill this in by mm/dd/yyyy. It's better to split that form apart into three values on how you want it, as you've stated `dd/mm/yyyy`

Now you want to check if the date hasn't come yet, before that do check if the day variable is between `($day > 0 && $day <= 31) && $month > 0 && $month <= 12 && $year >= 0 && $year <= date('Y')` as now you can format those numbers to the unix timestamp to see if the number has passed yet.

```
<?php
  $date = new DateTime("$year-$month-$day");

  echo $date->getTimestamp() > time() ? 'use submitted a date in the future' : 'user submitted a date in the past';

  // keep in mind that any date before 31/12/1899 will not work.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this function:

```
function isAdult(day, month, year) {
    var age = 18;
    var mydate = new Date();
        mydate.setFullYear(year, month-1, day);
    var currdate = new Date();
    var setDate = new Date();         
        setDate.setFullYear(mydate.getFullYear() + age, month-1, day);

    if ((currdate - setDate) > 0) return true;
    return false;
}

var dob = new Date("1980-12-01");
if( isAdult(dob.getDate(), dob.getMonth()+1, dob.getFullYear()) ) {
    console.log("Adult")
}
```